# Use gorm insert data has pro

Tags: go

When i use gorm insert data with InsertFileInfo struct, the first struct insert success,the second insert fail.

What diff two struct?Why Second struct fail?

[image]

Comment: Show the code you are executing, not just the struct. And show your code as text, not screenshots. You may also want to read the gorm docs on [embedded structs](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#embedded_struct).

Comment: This question requires more details. Please post the code you use to create and insert data. Also please don't embed screenshots, instead paste code directly as text, so people can easily experiment with it.

Comment: thx for help, add embedded is useful

Comment: Add Debug to query or use db LogMode to log queries; Issue seems to be the query is trying to put no value into mod_time and field is not null so it fails; Solution can be either add default value or fix the query generated